# Why is one instance of my OpsWorks stack skipping my deploys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

It's the second time I'm deploying an app and this same instance skips the deploy. The release is updated and no other instance is showing any kind of abnormality.

[Print (I'm unable to show it here yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuFdB.png)

Can anyone help me understand why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: check if the setup was successful on the instance, plus if you are using a custom layer, then Opsworks detects that and can skip certain actions.

Comment: @samtoddler it appears that after the deploy the instance shuts down (with a failure flag) then runs setup and is good to go.